# Is there a computationally optimal way to determine the number of digits in a range of natural numbers?

Tags: math, rust, numbers, formula, string-length

Assume the numbers are in base 10 and each subsequent number is 1 more than the previous.

A naïve solution would be:

```rust
fn range_digits(start: usize, end: usize) -> usize {
    (start..=end).fold(0, |a, b| a + b.to_string().len())
}
```

Which gives the output `88915` for the inputs `5` for `start` and `20005` for `end`.

The best solution I could come up with was:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

fn digits(a: usize) -> usize {
    ((a as f64).log10() as usize) + 1
}

// Present conversions and type casts could be problematic for certain inputs.
fn range_digits(start: usize, end: usize) -> usize {
    let (start_digits, end_digits) = (digits(start), digits(end));
    if start_digits == end_digits {
        (end - start + 1) * start_digits
    } else {
        let (a, b) = (
            10_usize.pow(start_digits.try_into().unwrap()) - 1,
            10_usize.pow((end_digits - 1).try_into().unwrap()) as usize,
        );
        (digits(a + 1)..=digits(b - 1)).fold(0, |acc, elem| {
            acc + 9 * elem * 10_usize.pow((elem - 1).try_into().unwrap())
        }) + ((a - start + 1) * start_digits)
            + ((end - b + 1) * end_digits)
    }
}
```

But I'm wondering if there's a yet more computationally efficient/optimal solution/formula.

Comment: For a more optimal solution, note that you can break the problem into smaller problems. e.g. if start is 5 and end is 20005, you can think about the cases of 10-99, 100-999, 1000-9999 separately. Then you can add the special end cases of 5-9 and 10000-20005.

Comment: Start by finding how many digits are in the start and end values and go from there.

Comment: But this question doesn't feel entirely suitable for SO, since it isn't likely to be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Readability over performance. If in doubt, [write benchmarks](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.4.0/book/benchmark-tests.html).

Comment: @PeterHall That's what my second solution does.

Comment: Then I think we are done here?

Comment: @hellow I did write benchmarks (using criterion-rs). My second solution is faster than my first, but I'm still wondering if there's a less computationally complex/optimal solution/formula.

Comment: @nicoty what about `pub fn range_digits(start: usize, end: usize) -> usize { (start..=end).map(|b| (b as f64).log10() as usize + 1).sum() }` ?

Comment: This should be measurable in single digit microseconds.  If your _**real**_ problem is doing this for millions of different inputs then the optmisations you're looking for will be dependent on the complete problem. Otherwise you are looking at microbenchmarks in isolation, which is pretty useless.

Comment: @hellow That's essentially what my naïve solution does, and it's more computationally complex as it's iterating through each number in the range, whereas my second solution is faster as it does essentially what PeterHall explained.

Comment: @nicoty my solution does not convert the number into a string, which is a huge difference in terms of computation needed (not speaking about allocating here!). The solution should differ a lot from your naïve solution. As said, if in doubt, benchmark. I won't argue, that your second solution is faster than mine, but it's a different approach worth testing and benchmarking, don't you think? I'm curious about the numbers ;) BTW: you are iterating over every number as well. The `sum` code should be as fast as a manual `fold` implementation, but more readable IMHO.

Comment: @hellow Ah that's true. I'm indeed curious if it's faster. I'll include it in the benchmarks and let you know the results :) Fwiw, I don't my second solution is iterating over every number. I think it's only "iterating" over the numbers 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc., right?

Comment: @hellow According to the benchmarks (which is not representative of all inputs as it's only testing for when `start` is `5` and `end` is `20005`), my second solution is about 4x faster than yours, but your solution is about 3x faster than my first solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest approach probably is to do this completely with integer arithmetic. Switching between floats and integers is expensive. Here's a simple implementation. I didn't perform any benchmarks on it.

```
fn digits_in_range(base: usize, range: Range<usize>) -> usize {
    let mut result;
    let mut power = 1;
    let mut current_digits = 0;
    while power <= range.start {
        power *= base;
        current_digits += 1;
    }
    result = (power - range.start) * current_digits;
    while power <= range.end {
        let last_power = power;
        power *= base;
        current_digits += 1;
        result += (power - last_power) * current_digits;
    }
    result -= (power - range.end) * current_digits;
    result
}
```

This takes the number system base as the first argument, and a `Range` as the second argument. Note that a `Range` excludes its endpoint, so it's not included in the count. You can change this to `RangeInclusive` with a small correction to the code if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, for the interesting solution. I'm curious if it's indeed faster so I'll benchmark it too. Just fwiw, I edited my second solution to no longer use floats before you added your answer, so it longer does any switching between integer and floats (although it still does some conversions between different types of integers).

Comment: Conversions between different types of integers are cheap, so I don't think there is a lot of measureable difference now.

Comment: Wait, you still convert to floats in the `digits()` function, don't you?

Comment: Your implementation also gives a wrong result for the range from 5 to 6.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry you're correct. I only changed the `range_digits` function and forgot that the `digits` function also used floats.

Comment: Good job spotting the bug, thanks! I've edited my second solution with hopefully a fixed version. Fwiw, your solution definitely seems much faster than mine, at least according to the benchmarks I ran, nice job on it! I'm marking your answer as the accepted answer for now, until someone beats it :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

- Hard-code the number of digits for intervals of the form `[0, 10**k - 1]`;
- Using extremely simple integer arithmetic to deduce the value for any interval `[a, b]`.

Below is code assuming `0 <= a <= b < 10**10`.

I don't know rust, so this is python; but the algorithm is so simple that I believe the logic of the code is very understandable.

```py
def get_next_power_of_10(n):
  v, p = 10, 1
  while v <= n:
    v *= 10
    p += 1
  return (v, p)

# d[k] = number of digits in interval [0, 10**k - 1]
d = [1, 10, 190, 2890, 38890, 488890, 5888890, 68888890, 788888890, 8888888890, 98888888890]

def get_number_of_digits_in_0_n(n):
  (v, p) = get_next_power_of_10(n)
  return d[p] - p * (v - 1 - n)

def get_number_of_digits_in_interval(a, b):
  return get_number_of_digits_in_0_n(b) - get_number_of_digits_in_0_n(a-1)
```